# Django dot-lookup syntax to access variable attributes

Tags: django

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The template system uses dot-lookup syntax to access variable attributes. In the example of {{ question.question_text }}, first Django does a dictionary lookup on the object question. Failing that, it tries an attribute lookup – which works, in this case. If attribute lookup had failed, it would’ve tried a list-index lookup.

What is the difference between dictionary, attribute, and list-index lookup?

Comment: This is detailed in the documentation with examples [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups)

Comment: in {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}, question is the context but how is choice accessed from this since choice was never passed  as a context to the template?

Comment: What? Er, what? `choice_set` is an attribute of `question`. Why would you think it would need to be passed to the context?

Comment: question.choice_set.all evaluates to what then? how is choice.choice_text accesible if Choice was not passed as context?

Comment: `choice` is defined by the for loop. This is absolutely standard programming. And what `question.choice_set.all` evaluates to is described in *literally the second paragraph* under where you copied the code from.

Comment: <h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1> is the only one printed. the rest of the code produce no output, A check from my database says there are choices associated with question from the django tutorial?

Comment: I guess question.choice_set.all evaluates to the choice model.

Comment: Django's ORM is doing some extra work for you in this context. I don't have to pass choices as context to the template via the view because the relationship is a part of the object we are working with here. It's the same deal as working in the shell and you ask for a question object then look at ```question.choice_set.all()``` it's just a little different looking in the template.

Answer (score 10):

**Dot lookup in Django templates:**

When the Django template system encounters a dot in a variable name `{{foo.bar}}`, it tries the lookups, in the below order:

> The template system uses the first lookup type that works. It’s
>   short-circuit logic.

**1. Dictionary lookup**

In dictionary lookup, it will try to perform lookup assuming `foo` as a dictionary and `bar` as a key in that dictionary.

```
foo["bar"] # perform dictionary lookup
```

**2. Attribute lookup.**

When the dictionary lookup fails, it performs attribute lookup i.e try to access `bar` attribute in `foo`.

```
foo.bar # perform attribute lookup
```

**3. List-index lookup.**

When the attribute lookup fails, it will try to perform list-index lookup i.e try to access `bar` index in `foo`.

```
foo[bar] # perform index lookup
```

Example from [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups):

```
>>> from django.template import Context, Template
>>> t = Template("My name is {{ person.first_name }}.")

# Dictionary lookup
>>> d = {"person": {"first_name": "Joe", "last_name": "Johnson"}}
>>> t.render(Context(d))
"My name is Joe."

# Attribute lookup
>>> class PersonClass: pass
>>> p = PersonClass()
>>> p.first_name = "Ron"
>>> p.last_name = "Nasty"
>>> t.render(Context({"person": p}))
"My name is Ron."

# List-Index lookup
>>> t = Template("The first stooge in the list is {{ stooges.0 }}.")
>>> c = Context({"stooges": ["Larry", "Curly", "Moe"]})
>>> t.render(c)
"The first stooge in the list is Larry."
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups):

```
Dictionary lookup. Example: foo["bar"]
Attribute lookup. Example: foo.bar
List-index lookup. Example: foo[bar]
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between those is thus:

1. Dictionary:

Django's template language tries to see if the thing you're working with is a dictionary and it tries to look up the property as if the object were a dictionary data structure.

2. Attribute

If that doesn't work, Django's template language will attempt to get that data by treating it like an attribute of the object (which could also be a method to call on the object like if you have something along the lines of `question.is_published()`)

3. List Index

If that doesn't work the template renderer will then try and see if it is working with a list by attempting to access that index. For example, if you do have a list (like an evaluated queryset) you could something like `{{ questions.0 }}` to get the first question in a list.

### What I think you are really asking:

Working with the template language can be weird at first depending on your background. Like I mentioned in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767629/django-dot-lookup-syntax-to-access-variable-attributes?noredirect=1#comment53379078_32767629), you can traverse relationships (that is, go between tables in your quest for data to inject into your template) without explicitly passing it into the context data for the view. That said, you can certainly abuse this power and you should use caution when traversing many relations because that will cause additional lookups.

To get a good feel for how that works, you should spend a while in the shell (I like to use django-extension's shell_plus) playing around with your models' API to see how you can access relationships (through Foreign Keys, Many to Many and One to One relations). Again, this does require additional lookups (that's what select_related and prefetch_related can be used to mitigate).